# Unbale to run Fanuc Focas Console App(.net Core) on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, c#, .net, console-application, raspberry-pi3

I had Created Console App(.Net Framework) which was working on windows and giving me an Fanuc Controller data as per my expectation. Now i want to run the same application on raspberry pi. So i have converted .net Framework to .net Core console application starting Fwlib32.cs was unable to load FwLib32.dll  and i was getting the error to overcome that i replaced Fwlib32.cs by Fwlib64.cs and i have installed Fwlib64 1.0.0 from Nuget Packages into my console project and error has been solved and getting the results as previous, i have published Project to Folder as Selfcontained and Linux-arm, i have transfered all the files to raspberry pi but i am getting an error now as below

pi@raspberrypi:~/FanucCore $ ./FanucCore1
Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'FWLIB64.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libFWLIB64.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at Focas1.cnc_allclibhndl3(Object ip, UInt16 port, Int32 timeout, UInt16& FlibHndl)
at FanucFocasApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\FanucCore1\FanucCore1\Program.cs:line 21
Aborted

i have used Raspberry pi 3 Model B+

I want solution for this i dont know why FwLib64.dll is not supporting i want to build edge device that can capture data from Fanuc Controller through Fanuc Focas Libraries